# Debugging JUnit Tests in a Hibernate driven Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, debugging, junit

Maybe this has been answered already, but i did not find any suggestions out there...
My Project is a Spring Utility Project, the database i use is MySQL and for persistence i´m using Hibernate in combination with c3p0 connection pooling. i´m on spring 3.2 and hibernate 3.5.
So here is what i want to do:
I want to debug a JUnit test, step over some persistence functions (save, update, etc. ) and then check the entries manually in the database via SQL. Because of the JUnit tests always running in a transaction, i cannot check the entries in the database, because a rollback happens every time a test finished / a commit never occurs.

Is there a way to fake transaction existence, or bypassing them during JUnit tests?

Comment: Do you need to put the breakpoint after the transaction has rolled back? If you can put the breakpoint in the test before the transaction rollback, then you have a few more options.

Comment: No, before the rollback happens. I need to take a look at the database during the transaction. But the more i think about this the more i think that it´s kind of a conceptual problem, because the actual sense of junit is, that they will always roll back for not affecting other tests... so the transaction is needed :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than fake transaction existence, the best approach to looking at the database while the transaction is taking place is to query with an isolation level that allows dirty reads. The mechanism for doing this varies from database to database, and in MySQL you can use

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

prior to querying.

Clearly you will also need to force Hibernate to flush writes to the database during your test, and set your breakpoint after the flush.

Comment: Yes. Transaction isolation was the keyword! I have now moved my testing environment to an h2 database and figured that out during studying their docs. "Read uncommited" was the setting that helped me debugging my tests better! Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can flush the transaction in Hibernate during your debugging session and force Spring/Hibernate to write to the database.

Or you can turn off transactions for your debugging session.

Comment: Unfortunately flushing is not the solution, because the "flushed" entities are still in the transaction and not visible to my sql queries. But turning off transactions completely for my testing environment may be a solution. I´ll give it a try!